# Reading an optional attribute of a XML Node in python3

Tags: python-3.x, xml, element, sax

I'm trying to read a XML file in SAX in Python3, because in my pet project I have in inptu a full directory of XML file representing some GTD projects[1](https://hamberg.no/gtd) .

The file has this format

```
<project name = "name of project">
<action number="2" > action to do</action>
</project>
```

my SAX parsing is in the class [MyHandler](https://github.com/alepuzio/Parsing-Getting-Things-Done/blob/develop/parsinggettingthingsdone/parser_xml.py) and my problem is that I have defined the attribute "*number*" as optional, but it's not working.

In the instruction

```
   def startElement(self, tagName, attrs):
     #etc
     elif tag_name.isAction():
            self.priority = attrs['number'] if 'number' in tagName else '0'
```

I verify if the current tag is an Action tag: if yes, I populate the self.priority attribute of the class reading the XML attribute "number" if exists, otherwise I put '0'.

My problem is

> attrs['number'] if 'number' in tagName

that is false in every case

How I can verify, in *startElement* method, if the *tagName* has an attribute '*number*'?

In stackoverflow I found sonly examples with Stax

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tagName` doesn't "have" anything, it's just a string.
The `in` operator checks for a substring `number` inside the name of the tag. `'number' in 'somenumberthing'`  evaluates to true. Clearly not what you want here.

The `attr` has the actual values; the condition you are looking for is rather: "if the attributes has a value for the key 'number'", e.g:

```py
self.priority = attrs['number'] if 'number' in attrs else '0'
```

This is a very common pattern for dict like objects, and I assume this is what SAX gives you so I would recommend using the `get` method with the default value:

```py
self.priority = attrs.get('number', default='0')
```